# Issue in loading after modifying an html string as NSString

Tags: html, ios, iphone, nsstring

I face a strange issue:

```
    <font style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ef3e42; font-size: 12px; 
line-height:24px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;”>Starting Location</font></td>
```

I load the above HTML file in to an NSString. And load it to the mail client mailBody. Everything works fine.
However when I load the HTML file, and supply the Starting location value as follows:

```
NSString *htmlString = @“<font style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ef3e42; font-size: 12px; line-height:24px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;”>%@</font></td>”
NSString *locationString = @“My Custom Location”;
NSString *emailBodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString,locationString];
```

Please find the out put emailBodyString:

```
<font style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ef3e42; font-size: 12px; 
line-height:24px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100;”>My Custom Location</font></td>
```

The result looks almost expected. However the 100% changed to 100. And this is happening in the entire HTML string. Everywhere the % gets removed.

Can some one suggest me the cause or a work around for this issue.

Comment: NSLog remove the % thing (take it as format specifier). Is that HTML is working in mail body ?

Comment: yes. please dont bother about the HTML string. It works fine. The HTML string posted here is just a representation of the issue

Answer (score 0):

In a `NSString` you need to put `%%`  for each `%`. It is  a special character. Or you could try adding a escape `\` before them.